# help with StringJoin

Tags: string-manipulation

```
dollarWon := 100
"(" <> Style["$" <> ToString[dollarWon], If[dollarWon >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]] <> ")"
```

I am getting an error: String expected at position 2.
Isn't it possible to use Style in the above expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Style[..] is not a string. Convert it to string by using StandardForm format to preserve style information:

```
dollarWon := 100
"(" <> ToString[
    Style["$" <> ToString[dollarWon], 
    If[dollarWon >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]], StandardForm] <> ")"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be better of using `Row` in this case, which lets you show arbitrary objects in a row, like so:

```
dollarWon = 100
Row[{
  "(", 
  Style[
    "$" <> ToString[dollarWon], 
    If[dollarWon >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]
  ], 
  ")"
}]
```